# How to count non empty cols ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
id  col1  col2  col3
 1   ''    ''    bla
 2   ''    bla   bla 
 3   bla    ''    ''
```

I want to build a query that will retun how much cols are not empty for each id.

so the result would be :

```
id  sum  
 1   1
 2   2
 3   1
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, ((col1 != '') + (col2 != '') + (col3 != '')) as non_empty_count
from table;
```

Uses a trick where boolean true=1 and false=0 - so for each column non empty value ads 1 to count. Can be seen in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/751df2/5

Comment: I like this answer, I didnt know that boolean in Mysql is 0/1

Comment: @54l3d yes, nice for "sum(is_active = 1) as active_count" too